# New tag proposal: decision-making

Tags: discussion, tags

Regarding my question [Decision and negotiation of long term time-consuming job](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/6564/decision-and-negotiation-of-long-term-time-consuming-job) I was going to add the tag [decision-making](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/decision-making) but surprisingly I did not find it in the list. I was surprised, in my mind I was taking it as granted in this site.

I suggest to add the [decision-making](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/decision-making) tag for questions about taking difficult decisions and get advices and experiences of other users.

I don't know maybe it could be opinion based but in such matters opinions and experiences of others can be of high value to help in decision making.

Comment: The subject for the tag, as presented, seems more like a discussion than a Q&A. Perhaps a chat channel would be a better option.